# Bootstrap Date Picker isn't working on second input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and using [this](http://themeforest.net/item/shamcey-metro-style-admin-template/4566092) template.

I'm having this problem about datepicker, and a few other similar things in this template.
When I try to use the input for second time, for example: input for datepicker, the second datepicker won't even show the calendar when I focus on the input, only the first one pop up. How can I rewrite this so that both show the calendar?

```
<div class="par">
<label>Check In</label>
<span class="field">
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="datein" class="input-small"/>
</span>
</div> 

<div class="par">
<label>Check Out</label>
<span class="field">
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="dateout" class="input-small"/>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all , **ID should always be unique**. you cannot have more than one element with same id and the reason behind this is , it not only gives W3C validation errors but also gives a lot of problem, one of which is you are facing now.

change your elements id to class and use class selector instead

```
   ....
 <input type="text" name="datein" class="input-small datepicker"/>
  .....
 <input type="text" name="dateout" class="input-small datepicker"/>
```

**javascript**

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

i removed id attr of your elements , add it if you need it , but make sure its unique

Comment: Do I need to change the id selector to a class selector in the css file?

Comment: yes you need to.. if you have CSS for datepicker and  want to apply those CSS to your element.

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker is binding to first element of DOM.

Use unique id

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker();
$('#datepicker2').datepicker();
```

Markup

```
<input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="datein" class="input-small"/>
<input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="datein" class="input-small"/>
```

To bind datepicker with different elements, or use class